# Django simple website with templates

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I want to serve some pages for a website at the project level in template form, so I can use a header and footer, etc.

I don't need a custom view for each page, I just want simple template rendering. I have a /templates folder for my project, but for every page I need to add a a url pattern settings.py

```
url(r'index.html',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),
```

Is there a way to simply map the whole contents of /templates to the url? Perhaps there is a better approach than this. I can see how to do this with media and static folders, but they don't provide template rendering

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're trying to do but does [flatpages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/flatpages/) address your problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes you can create a single url pattern to dynamically serve the htmls, but you'll have to create a custom view.

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.template import TemplateDoesNotExist
from django.http import Http404

class MyView(TemplateView):
    def get(self, request, page_name, *args, **kwargs):
        self.template_name = page_name
        response = super(MyView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
        try:
            return response.render()
        except TemplateDoesNotExist:
            raise Http404()
```

and create a single url pattern for you view

```
from myapp.views import MyView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<page_name>.+\.html)$', MyView.as_view()),
)
```

Comment: Can you please add the name of the files where you saved this code?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to make the template name match a querystring parameter that you pass to the view:

```
url(r'^(?P<template>[-\w]+)/$', 'render_template'),
url(r'^$', 'render_template'),


def render_template(request, template=None):
    if not template:
        template = 'home'

    return render(request, template + '.html')
```